# Is there a name for this variation ? (or just this setup in general)

Tags: opening

Recently I played a game against an international master, which I won, with a variation I prepared by having Deep Fritz 14 analyze each move individually, and now I'm wondering is there a specific name for this: (I play with white)

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. g3 g6 4. Bg2 Bg7 5. Nc3 0-0 6. Bf4
```

And to continue, I never actually played e3 in the game, but proceeded to set up e4 and eventually succeeded...

It doesn't have to be exactly this one, but I found that it doesn't fit in the description of the Barry attack or London system?

Comment: This setup is not popular enough to have a name. It is very unusual for White to fianchetto his light-squared bishop in either the London System or Barry Attack. 3.g3 is not considered to be an effective try for an advantage; after 3...Bf5 Black has already probably equalized (and has performed better than White in practice).

Comment: "I never actually played e3 in the game, but proceeded to set up 34 " Do you mean that you prepared and eventually played e4 (not 34)?

Comment: Oh I apologize, I'll edit that right away :)

Comment: Note that the replayer doesn't show the moves O-O 6. Bf4. I tried to correct this, but Captain_Shepard rejected the edit.

Comment: Oh Sorry Stephen, I figured it would we better left this way, with less moves it's easier to define the variation..

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it doesn't fit the description for the Barry Attack or London system. In neither system does white fianchetto his kingside bishop like that.

The black side looks characteristic of the Gruenfeld Defence. There are many ways for white to respond to the Gruenfeld. I haven't seen this one but that doesn't mean much since I rarely play the Gruenfeld as black.

Comment: Honestly it seems like some kind of a hybrid between the Catalan and London system lol :D To answer your remark though, my opponent did eventually play Bf5 where I responded with Nh4 he had to put his bishop on e6, and considering he had a pawn on c6 his bishop became quite a useless piece for a long time.